# Multiple versions of class with different base class

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a class `PoolExt` that inherits from multiprocessing's `Pool` class. Now I want to add a similar second class `ThreadPoolExt` that differs from `PoolExt` only in that it inherits from `ThreadPool` instead of `Pool`:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool

class PoolExt(Pool):
   def do_stuff(self):
      print("Doing stuff")

class ThreadPoolExt(ThreadPool):
   def do_stuff(self):
      print("Doing stuff")
```

I would like to avoid duplicate code for `ThreadPoolExt`. How would I achieve that most elegantly? My first approach was to overwrite the functions manually, but this requires me to specify the respective method names explicitly. Is there a simpler way?

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool

class PoolExt(Pool):
   def do_stuff(self):
      print("Doing stuff")

class ThreadPoolExt(ThreadPool):
   pass

ThreadPoolExt.do_stuff = PoolExt.do_stuff
```

Of course in real life I would have more and longer methods to handle.

Comment: Look into mixin classes.

Comment: Mixins? I.e. a base class which implements the repetitive code, and then multiple-inheritance child classes which inherit the base class *and* `Pool`…

Comment: This sounds like what I need. The order of the base classes then determine which function is used at the end?